# React and Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i'm working with react and typescript to build an application, but typescript seems to not work properly, i'll post my code so u can understand.

**Here is the component TextField**

```
/// <reference path="../../../../typings/index.d.ts" />
import * as React from 'react';

interface ITextFieldProps extends React.Props<TextField> {
    id: number,
    label: string,
    placeholder?: string,
    required?: boolean
}

interface ITextFieldState {
    value: string
}

export default class TextField extends React.Component<ITextFieldProps, ITextFieldState> {

    public state: ITextFieldState;

    public render() {
        return (
            <div className="textfield-default">
                <label>{this.props.label}</label>
                {this.props.id}
                <input
                    placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
                    required={ this.props.required ? 'required' : '' }
                    />
            </div>
        );
    }

}
```

**And here is where i start the component:**

```
<TextField id="abs" />
```

The problem is, that i'm asking in the interface of the component that "id" need to be a number, and "label" dosnt have the "?" on it so it should be passed...
But it works, dont give me any error not in compile and even in the console.
Any tips?

Cheers!

Comment: Still dont got it working, so if anyone know the path to do it, cheers!

Comment: Are you seeing other compile errors, e.g. if you do something like `let foo = 4; foo = "four";` in your render method?

Comment: Doing this i receive a compile error and VSCODE hint too:
"error TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'."
@TomFenech

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the issue if you use `React.createElement(TextField, { id: "abs" })` instead of the JSX syntax?

Comment: React.createElement(TextField, { id: "abs" }) works perfectly, VSCODE throws errors at development time, and my prompt throws errors too, this way it works like a charm, but there is no way i can work with JSX? The sintax is way better, thanks for the attention @TomFenech

Comment: Guys i discovered that this was a typescript error, so i did a post on typescript git and if u guys want to follow: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10595#issuecomment-243988902